# Reading csv to insert in mysql. fill empty columns with previous line

Tags: php, mysql, csv, insert

I have a csv file. I'm trying to read this file and import data to mysql database.

For example

```
OrderID,ProductId,ProductDescription
100001962,15,Product1
"",32,Product2
"",31,Product3
100001546,24,Product4
```

**How can i have my database like**

```
100001962,15,Product1
100001962,32,Product2
100001962,31,Product3
100001546,24,Product4
```

new.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="csv" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
require_once 'db.php';
if($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0){
$name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
$ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['csv']['name'])));
$type = $_FILES['csv']['type'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

// check the file is a csv
if($ext === 'csv'){
    if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    // necessary if a large csv file
    set_time_limit(0);
    mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
    $success = 0;
    $nosuccess = 0;
        while(( $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            // number of fields in the csv
            $csv[$row]['col1'] = str_replace("'", " ", $data[0]);//orderid
            $csv[$row]['col2'] = str_replace("'", " ", $data[1]);//productid
            $csv[$row]['col3'] = str_replace("'", " ", $data[2]);//productdesc

            if ($csv[$row]['col1']==0){
                if ($csv[$row-1]['col1']!=0){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO csv (orderid, orderdate, orderstatus) VALUES ('". $csv[$row-1]['col1']."','". $csv[$row-1]['col2']."','". $csv[$row-1]['col3']."')";
                }
                if ($csv[$row-2]['col1']!=0){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO csv (orderid, orderdate, orderstatus) VALUES ('". $csv[$row-2]['col1']."','". $csv[$row-2]['col2']."','". $csv[$row-2]['col3']."')";
                }
                //etc 
            }
            else
            {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO csv (orderid, orderdate, orderstatus) VALUES ('". $csv[$row]['col1']."','". $csv[$row]['col2']."','". $csv[$row]['col3']."')";
            }
            mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        }
    }
}
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking 'col1' to be an empty string rather than 0?

Comment: I tried if ($csv[$row-1]['col1']!="") and if ($csv[$row-1]['col1']!==NULL) but nothing.

Comment: Have you checked what the values actually are in each row. Also, what I would do is to create a variable for the OrderID which is only modified when you have one specified, then you don't need to go searching back previous rows until you find one. The only issue that has (& also your code) is what happens if the very first entry has no order number - but if that cant occur, then no problem.

Comment: nice trick this, thank you